# Define method parameters for meta programming in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In Ruby, we can define instance methods with meta-programming like:

```
define_method(:hi) { 'Hello, SO world!' } # => :hi
hi                                        # => "Hello, SO world!"
```

This way, it is possible to define a method with a *dynamic name*:

```
dynamic_name = :hi                                 # => :hi
define_method(dynamic_name) { 'Hello, SO world!' } # => :hi
hi                                                 # => "Hello, SO world!"
```

We can also inject arguments in to a dynamic method:

```
dynamic_name = :hi # => :hi
define_method(dynamic_name) do |arg1, arg2, &block|
  'Hello, SO world!'
end                # => :hi
hi(42, 42) { 42 }  # => "Hello, SO world!"
```

So far, so good.

But how could we do to inject *dynamic arguments*?
Would it be possible to replace `arg1, arg2, &block` by a dynamic notation?

Thanks for any tips, best practices, or even ideas.

**Edit**:

In other words, I would like to dynamically also define the parameters and the block of an instance method.

However, I would like to do so with a particular number of parameters (which could be 0), an array in option, and to finish the block of the method.

This way, I could avoid having methods such as:

```
dynamic_name = :hi      # => :hi
define_method(dynamic_name) do |*args, &block|
  'f'
end                     # => :hi
hi                      # => "f"
hi(:foo)                # => "f"
hi(:foo, :fooo)         # => "f"
hi(:foo, :fooo, :foooo) # => "f"
```

...which is a nonsense, because here we can give to the method an infinite number of unused parameters.  I would like to avoid this situation.

**Edit 2**:

The reason is the following:

In Ruby, when we need a method which do not need any parameters, we can simply do:

```
def my_method
  "Hello, SO world!"
end
```

However, if instead I do this:

```
def my_method(*args)
  "Hello, SO world!"
end
```

...the result is still the same, but because the parameter (the array `args`) is useless, it would be better to keep it simple by removing it from the method.

Comment: Why not just use a splat?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean? I don't understand...
Oh! Got it! with `*args, &block`.
Yes, but I would prefer to define a method with no arguments, in order to avoid having an args instance which would be equal to en empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing an array or dictionary.

UPDATE:

```
if condition1
  class_eval <<-EVAL
    def #{"my_method"}(arg1)
    end
  EVAL
else  
    class_eval <<-EVAL
      def #{"my_method"}
      end
  EVAL
end
```

UPDATE2:

```
if condition1
  self.instance_eval <<-EVAL
    def #{"my_method"}(arg1)
    end
  EVAL
else  
    self.instance_eval <<-EVAL
      def #{"my_method"}
      end
  EVAL
end
```

UPDATE3:

```
# or
self.instance_eval("def method1(arg1) puts 'hellowa' + arg1.to_s; end")
self.instance_eval("def method2() puts 'hellowa2'; end")

# and then
method1(33) # => hellowa33
method2 # => hellowa2
```

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I would like to define a method with no arguments at all, when `args` is empty...

Comment: I don't understand exactly, sorry. Maybe specifying a default value [] for an array?

Comment: Your solution is passing, but for 2 cases. Is there a global way to define params? I mean, in order to handle cases such as:
`()`,
`(arg)`,
`(arg1, arg2)`,
`(arg, *args)`,
`(arg, *args, &block)`,
`(arg, *args, **options, &block)`, etc. Maybe it's impossible, I don't know.
Also, it would be awesome without using `class_eval`.

Comment: @Zagzag.., updated. `my_method` should be available globally.

Comment: as well as method1 and method2

Comment: You're completely right, アレックス. My question looks impossible, but you're answer was very helpful! Thank man!